# Define dateTime format in xsd

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

At my work we load excel files and save them in the database.
This is basically the flow:
We import data into a DataSet from an Excel file, where each sheet is loaded into its own DataTable inside the DataSet. After populating the DataDet, i want to validate the data inside the DataSet, let's say the first DataTable. I get xml from the DataTable by using WriteXml() method of the DataTable class and load this xml into an XDocument. I then use the Validate() method of the XDocument class with a predefined xsd, which is loaded into a XmlSchemaSet object.

The problem is that the data in the excel is stored in a format that is different from the format of dateTime in xsd.
We get Excel files with datetime columns formatted like thie: **'12/01/2015  12:44:45'**, whereas the dateTime format in xsd should be like this: **'2015-01-12T12:44:45'**

Is it possible to define custom dateTime format in an xsd file?

For example, instead of **'2015-01-12T12:44:45'**, I would like it to be  **'12/01/2015  12:44:45'**, so my xml element would look like this:

```
<createDate>12/01/2015  12:44:45>/createDate>
```

In addition, i wouldn't mind if the **time part would be ignored altogether**.

In addition, another custom xsd format i need is like this:  `378,216.00`

Is it possible to define it in my xsd file?

Here is this code where we do the validation of the xml, retrieved from the datatable

```
public string[] ValidateExcelFromXsdFile(string schemaUri)
    {
        _validationErrors.Clear();

        var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add("", schemaUri);

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(GetXml(_dataSetFromExcel.Tables[0]));

        doc.Validate(schemas, (sender, args) => _validationErrors.Add(args.Message));

        return _validationErrors.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: You do want the c# code to serialize/export to write this special dateTimeFormat, do you? In this case, please add your source code. In case I misunderstood you, please clarify.

Comment: No, I apologize, that is not what I meant.   I import data into a DataSet from an Excel file, where each sheet is loaded into its own DataTable inside the DataSet. After populating the DataDet, i want to validate the data inside the DataSet, let's say the first DataTable. I get xml from the DataTable by using WriteXml() method of the DataTable class and load this xml into an XDocument. I then use the Validate() method of the XDocument class with a predefined xsd, which is loaded into a XmlSchemaSet object.

Comment: And here is the code `public string[] ValidateExcelFromXsdFile(string schemaUri)
        {
            _validationErrors.Clear();

            var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
            schemas.Add("", schemaUri);

            var doc = XDocument.Parse(GetXml(_dataSetFromExcel.Tables[0]));

            doc.Validate(schemas, (sender, args) => _validationErrors.Add(args.Message));

            return _validationErrors.ToArray();
        }`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, especially code. Putting it in comments means it's easily missed, and it can't be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a pattern for strings in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' using a regular expression, but the resulting value won't be an xs:dateTime, and checking for full validity (leap years etc) is a bit of a nightmare (it can be done, but leads to a regular expression that's about a mile long).

A better solution here might the transform-then-validate pattern, where you preprocess the input document (into standard XSD format) before validating it. You can even do some of the validation during the preprocessing phase if you choose.

The Saxon schema processor has an preprocess facet which allows you to declare some rearrangement of a value prior to schema processing, which is exactly what you need here (for both your use cases), but unfortunately it's not standard.

Answer (score -1):

Check this site - there you have DateTime data type http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp

Also Date and Time Data Types paragraph will allows you to adjust the rule to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof, I noticed that there is a pattern available for xsd. Do you know how to use it?